# Quickie regular expression stuck

Tags: java

I have a line of stringy goodness:

```
"B8&amp;soundFile=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faeero%2Fj34d1.mp3%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faudfgo%2set4.mp3"
```

Can I use regular expressions to just extract the http up to mp3 for all times it exists?

I have tried reading the documents for regular expressions but none mention how to go FROM http to mp3.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `http.+?mp3`

Comment: I'm using the substring method now, but since this works as the regexp (just tried!) I have no choice but to honor you with leTick.  :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you directly go for index based String operation.

```
 String data = "B8&amp;soundFile=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faeero%2Fj34d1.mp3%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faudfgo%2set4.mp3";  

 System.out.println(data.substring(data.indexOf("http"), data.indexOf(".mp3")));
```

**Output :**

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faeero%2Fj34d1
B8&amp;soundFile=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faeero%2Fj34d1.mp3%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faudfgo%2set4.mp3
```

Comment: !!!!!!! Why didn't I think of that!  Trying this now.  Theres always an easy way to do things without resorting to regexps.  Thankyou.

Comment: I'll throw in my paranoia here and ask that "http" or ".mp3" chouldn't occur inside the target string?

Comment: @David19801 Index would be better solution here

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't do this with a regex. URL decode it, break it up by tokens, and parse it using [Java's URL class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Answer (score 0):

the following should do it (assuming you want the http and mp3 as part of your match):

```
.*(http.*mp3)
```

if you just want the bits between then:

```
.*http(.*)mp3
```

for example:

```
    String input = "B8&amp;soundFile=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faeero%2Fj34d1.mp3%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faudfgo%2set4.mp3";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(http.*mp3)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

gives us

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Faudfgo%2set4.mp3
```